# what do the branch points of a function tell about the function?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

If we know the zeros of an entire function, we have the Weierstrasse construction of the function.

How about the branch points?

Is there any topology involved?

Comment: You can construct a lot of entire functions with the only branch point  0.

Comment: sorry, but an entire function cannot have any branch point.

Comment: I was wrong, I misunderstood the English terminology. Branch point is else what I thought. It would have been smarter if I'd have looked it at wikipedia before I left a comment.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you want to know, and can you formulate your question more carefully? The question is vague and ungrammatical as currently stated. For instance, is there any topology behind **what**?

Comment: Branch points of a holomorphic function has a completely geometric description : to every holomorphic function $f : \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$, there is an attached real 2-manifold called "Riemann surfaces" which can be realized as branched covers of $\Bbb CP^1$ (the 2-sphere). The branch points of $f$ are essentially the points in $\Bbb CP^1$ which has no evenly covered neighborhood under the covering map. Looping about the branch points and lifting those loops tells one a lot about the sheet structure of the corresponding Riemann surface : this phenomenon is formally called monodromy of the function

Comment: Any good reference?